# Skummet Fails To Compile: Could not find or load main class

Tags: clojure, compiler-errors, leiningen

This happens even if I create a new default project. I followed the setup instructions [here](https://github.com/alexander-yakushev/lein-skummet/wiki), and this is what my project.clj looks like:

```
(defproject stest "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "FIXME: write description"
  :url "http://example.com/FIXME"
  :license {:name "Eclipse Public License"
            :url "http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html"}
  :dependencies [[org.skummet/clojure "1.7.0-r2"]]
  :exclusions [[org.clojure/clojure]]
  :plugins [[org.skummet/lein-skummet "0.2.2"]]
  :main ^:skip-aot stest.core
  :target-path "target/%s"
  :profiles {:default []
             :uberjar {:aot :all}})
```

This is my core.clj:

```
(ns stest.core
  (:gen-class))

(defn -main
  "I don't do a whole lot ... yet."
  [& args]
  (println "Hello, World!"))
```

I didn't modify anything else in the default project. This is what I get when I attempt any sort of compilation:

```
$ lein skummet compile
$ lein skummet run
Error: Could not find or load main class stest.core
$ lein skummet jar
Warning: The Main-Class specified does not exist within the jar. It may not be executable as expected. A gen-class directive may be missing in the namespace which contains the main method, or the namespace has not been AOT-compiled.
Created [PATH OMITTED]/stest/target/uberjar+skummet/stest-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
Created [PATH OMITTED]/stest/target/uberjar/stest-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT-standalone.jar
```

What is the reason for this malfunction? I don't seem to be able to compile any project using skummet.

Comment: What is your directory structure? Specifically, where are project.clj and core.clj?

Comment: project.clj is in the root directory of the project, core.clj is under src/stest/core.clj, in other words they are where lein put them by default.

Comment: Do you have this file in place: https://github.com/alexander-yakushev/lein-skummet/blob/master/src/leiningen/skummet.clj?

Comment: I can't seem to find it. Where should it be?

Comment: The Github link above shows you where it should be: `PROJECT-ROOT/src/leiningen/skummet.clj`

Comment: I put it in that folder in my project, but I still get the same error. Are you sure I have to manually include a source file in my project to use skummet? Or am I meant to put it somewhere else?

Comment: Actually no, that file is part of the library, in fact is the library, so that was poor advice. Try `lein clean` `lein deps`.

Comment: You should raise an issue with that library provider and point here. Also you can try using the current "0.2.3-SNAPSHOT" version by cloning the github repo and going `lein install`.

Comment: I notice that your profiles include an uberjar whereas the instructions don't. Forget about the jar part until `run` is working.